# Setting local image on Cordova's WKWebview using evaluateJavascript method

Tags: javascript, swift, iphone, cordova, wkwebview

I have an HTML file which contains local resource files such as CSS, js files inside its content. These local resource files are in zip format. My app uses Cordova's WKWebView to display this HTML file. I m trying to upload an image in one of the HTML image element on Cordova's WKWebView which is saved locally and HTML is not updating the image. I have an HTML image tag in local HTML like this.

```
<img id='image' style='display: block; height: 100%; width:100%; margin:0 auto;' />
```

And this image to load in this image tag is generated after the local HTML file is loaded in the Cordova's WKWebview. Once the image is generated, I am trying to update the image tag with the evaluate javascript method like this.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *base64Str = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];     
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('image-id').src='data:image/png;base64,%@'",base64Str];
[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];
```

It is working fine on normal WKWebView. Is there any workaround solution for my scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your app app just using the Cordova WebView as an embed or is it a full Cordova app?

Comment: It is using Cordova WebView as an embed. The app comprises both native and cordova bits in it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html#using-cdvviewcontroller), it looks like you need to use `CDVViewController` and reference the `webView` through that Controller.

My understanding is that this webView reference uses the webview engine that Cordova [defaults](https://cordova.apache.org/2021/02/07/deprecate-wkwebview-engine.html) too (As of `cordova-ios@6` defaults to `WKWebView`).

Otherwise you might need to [manually specify](https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/03/18/wkwebviewonly.html) the the `WKWebView` in `config.xml` for older versions of Cordova.

Comment: I am using CDVViewController's webview only. That is how it is loading the html initially. Its just I am not able to write image on top of that.

Comment: There are no specific error logs. I could see the image converted to base64 string and also get success message on completion handler of evaluate javascript method.